# How to save the backup file from ftp server and saved in local machine

Tags: vb.net

I want to save the backup file from ftp server to local machine.The code which i have used:

```
If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:/BluePearlsData")) Then

            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/BluePearlsData")

        End If
    Else
        If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists("c:/SHS_Data")) Then
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("c:/SHS_Data")
        End If
    End If

    Dim s As String = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh-mm tt")
    Using wc As New System.Net.WebClient
        If iPointer = 0 Then
            wc.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
            Dim path As String
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("c:/BluePearlsData" & "\SQL2008R2_797817_headstart_backup_" & s & ".bak", wc.DownloadString("filepath"), False)
```

This code works on local server but when i hosted it to server then it gives error i.e.

> ***Access denied "c:/BluePearlsData"***

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the rights to access the file.

Comment: But this code works fine on local server.